# Installing Silverstripe with puppet

Tags: vagrant, puppet, silverstripe

I'm trying to use puppet to create a default installation of Silverstripe for testing new projects. Is there a way to install silverstripe using just the commandline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `_ss_environment.php` file, then run `php framework/cli-script.php dev/build`. The default `mysite/_config.php` is set up for this already.

You can read more on the `_ss_environment.php` file in the [docs](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/environment-management).

Answer (score 0):

If your hosting environment either has composer or allows you to install software, using composer to install from the command line is an option.  Refer: [Installing and Upgrading with Composer](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/installation/composer)

Comment: but you still have to load up the installation page and specify db settings etc. bit redundant since puppet is setting those up anyway.